# problems with compass importing sprites

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass

I'm confused by how the directory structure works. For example, mine is like:

```
--compass
    --css
    --images
        --frontSprite
            Images
    -sass
        --_base.scss
        --advertiser.scss
    config.rb
```

When I try to import my images I am using:

```
@import "frontSprite/*.png";
```

in my _base.scss, but this generates me an error which I feel is related to not finding the directory correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please provide the error? It would be best if it's the full `--trace` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the correct directory structure depends on what you've set in your config.rb.
Should look like that:

```
images_dir = "images"
http_images_path = "/this/path/is/rendered/in/the/css/file"
```

`images_dir` tells compass where the images lie (relative to the config.rb) and the `http_images_path` defines what is actually rendered in the CSS-output.

Try the command `compass sprite "images/frontSprite/*.png"` (this will generate the sprite css-output) from within your compass directory to debug the path.

**Sidenote:** When you work with .pngs you should consider installing oily png, this will remarkable speed up the sprite generation process. It's extremely simple just use `gem install oily_png` and Compass will automatically detect that it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Symfony & assetic

Go to config.yml & add this in parameters : 
`assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/App/PlayerBundle/Resources/public/assets/img/`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with compass in windows and solved it by editing this file:

```
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\compass-0.12.2\lib\compass\sprite_importer.rb
```

Change line 19:

```
-      Dir.glob(File.join(path, "**", glob))
+      Sass::Util.glob(File.join(path, "**", glob))
```

And line 78:

```
-        files = Dir[File.join(folder, uri)].sort
+        files = Sass::Util.glob(File.join(folder, uri)).sort
```

Save and it works!

Source:
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/commit/58babac01b56eddf63bac737f7f781d98f00f6b9
*It's an old patch, so I wonder why it isn't in latest version of compass?*